# Should we participate in SE Winter Bash in 2014?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

We did not opt-in to [Winter Bash 2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/).  I am proposing that we do in 2014, assuming the practice continues.

I chose to individually opt in this year (by selecting "I love hats!" from the seasonal menu) and I notice that some other users did as well.  After trying it I don't think hats significantly distract from the business of the site and I don't think anyone will seriously be put off by the amusing avatars.

I am proposing this during Winter Bash 2013 so that people can try it out or observe other SE sites and determine if they want this next year or not.  People will be able to individually opt out ("I hate hats!") if they do not like it.

**Up vote this question to support the proposal (i.e. participation in 2014); down vote it to disapprove.**

Comment: I have completely no idea what Winter Bash is and what you're talking about. Could you explain it?

Comment: @Artes I knew I forgot something.  I'm out of time now but later I'll add something.  For now you can look on Meta.StackOverflow for answers; it's mostly about silly hats. ;)

Comment: @Artes See here: http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/ To participate on this site, click on the snowflake on the topbar and press "I love hats".

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks for the link, I understand, though I'm not quite convinced there is anything interesting.

Comment: @Artes I don't think there's anything interesting either. On most other sites, you'll also find [silly](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/1470) and [undesirable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211728) [behaviour](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159599) from users just trying to game the hats. I would much rather this not be a feature of our site in the future as well, which is why I downvoted this question.

Comment: btw, @Mr.Wizard your list is not actually indicative or reflective of users participating in Winter Bash specifically on this site. Folks participating on other sites are also included in this site's list. For instance, Dominic Michaelis hasn't been on the site since Sep. and Michael Underwood since Oct. Several others on the list (F'x, whuber, hhh) haven't been around since Winter Bash started.

Comment: @rm-rf Okay, now I feel foolish.  Oh well, nothing new there. :^)

Comment: I think it's right and good that this is put to the vote. However, I don't support the proposition, and to follow from @rm-rf's comments, it seems that, of the users who do (assuming your list is exhaustive) not many are frequent posters.

Comment: I participate this just for curiosity, also think the little snowflake and some hats are cute. Didn't realize they can drive people into silly things.. :(

Comment: Like @silvia I just wanted to see what people were talking about (there being no info on this site). It's interesting but not surprising to learn that there are some who allow headgear to adversely affect their behaviour. But don't forget, not everyone is able to see themselves in the Top 10 Rep list  - perhaps this provides some much needed alternative incentives for people with lower "traditional" reputation scores?

Comment: added featured tag to get attention while people still have time to try this out.

Comment: I thought that this is on a per-user basis, so anyone can opt-in or out. How is this dependent on our community-voting? Is it like enough users have to opt-in to start the whole hat-business? Or a moderator has to opt-in? I fail I don't understand the system, could you please give a hint?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Yes, users can opt-in or opt-out, but to earn hats, they have to perform certain actions on the site. For example, you get a hat for upvoting 5 questions, for only upvoting in a day, for using up all your votes, etc. People don't worry much about badges for these because you can't wear badges (and you probably got them 20 months ago). On the other hand, a cute hat drives people to earn them as fast as possible so that they can put it on their gravatar. This leads to crazy upvoting of anything and everything so that they can earn and wear the hat within the next 5 mins.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Each site has 3 options — opt out site wide(no hats ever, like Math Overflow), have hats "off" by default (you have to opt-in to participate — this is what we have on our site) or have hats "on" by default and you earn hats for things you do on the site (you have to opt-out to not participate).

Comment: @rm-rf I really think you overestimate the "gaming" problem with the members of our community.  I think *most* of our users are more mature than that.  My feeling is that it would just add a bit of seasonal fun for people on break without harming the practicality or professionalism of the site.  If we try it next year and I'm wrong I'll eat my hat.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am not commenting on or estimating the problem on our site because I don't know who's participating (I can't see because I opted out) and I wasn't around frequently enough the past week to observe patterns myself. I do however read other metas/MSO and know that this is a problem on the network (also discussed in TL). Of course, one can dismiss the problem as being "seasonal" or "won't have long term effects" or "it's all in good fun", etc., but I'm just alerting everyone who wants to vote on this (since you asked for a vote) about the problems/concerns across the network.

Comment: @rm-rf That's entirely reasonable and I'm glad that you brought it up.  I'm just arguing my position as well. :-)

Comment: There was also some concern in chat yesterday re: nonsense upvoting (for example, a +1 for [this version](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/d6990550-d1cd-4f7c-a69b-f91de53566e3/view-source) of the question), that I think is related to the hats.

Comment: Since I activated the hat feature I have not even once, not for a single hat I did not already have, looked up the requirements that would help me retrieve them. It's more like, I got a hat, what did I do now. Even though it's admittedly a very, very small source of joy for me and I basically don't care, I think that as a concept it can be classified as seasonal fun indeed. I'm not convinced by adverse effects unless they can be quantified. Surely SE will not encourage something too harmful. For that reason I will up vote.

Comment: Thanks @rm-rf, your second piece answered my question! About the voting: I am completely neutral. Last time I had a hat, wind blew it off. Have a happy christmas/hanukkah/pagan-winter-solstice-festival all!

Comment: @István You too. :-)

Comment: @rm-rf I like your hat! :)

Comment: @cormullion What hat?  Oh, *THAT* hat.  Indeed!  Welcome to the club R.M.  If you can't beat 'em, join 'em?

Comment: @cormullion Thanks! :) Also, I'm collecting [jelly beans in the Stack Exchange UglyBar™](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XP4it.png) :)

Comment: @rm-rf That's hilarious!

Comment: Ha, looks like the naysayer [ended up with the most hats](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/mathematica.stackexchange.com) :P I swear, I didn't try! lol!

Comment: @rm-rf Well, you know what they say: "If you can't beat them, join them":)

Comment: Maybe next time we can do socks. Who wouldn't want decorative socks?